# How to align "Text" above the first column?

Tags: tables

I have two questions. First, I made this table and I would like to have the bold "Text" object aligned above the first column whenever it appears. Now it is displayed above the second column. I tried to change different things but it doesn't move.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}r}
\hline 
Description   & T & Source & Geography & Start & End & F \\ 
\hline 

& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Text}} \\ 

Manchester United & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 10 &   \\
Celtic            & 6 & 3 & 0 & 3 &  8 &   \\
Benfica           & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  7 &   \\
FC Copenhagen     & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &   \\

& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Text}} \\ 

Manchester United & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 10 &   \\
Celtic            & 6 & 3 & 0 & 3 &  8 &   \\
Benfica           & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  7 &   \\
FC Copenhagen     & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &   \\

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Second, I will enter this table horizontally with `landscape`, How can I make sure that the columns don't exceed the width of the page but fits the page nicely?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to place the table onto a landscape oriented page? Currently it fits perfectly fine into the textwidth of a portrait oriented standard article class page. Will you add more/longer text somewhere inthe table or will you add more columns? Please clarify.

Comment: To move the `\textbf{Text}` into the first column, remove the `&` right before the `\multicolumn`. Why do you use the `\multicolumn` in the first place? You can just remove it and get the same output.

Comment: @leandriis This was an example. The real one is going to be much bigger. That's why I used landscape. Any hint on to make it fit the page properly? Thanks for the other hint

Comment: How to ensure that a table fits into the textwidth entirely depends on its contents. Do you have a column with longer text in it? --> use `tabularx`. Do you have a lot of columns with short entries (numbers) --> `tabular*` and a reduced `\tabcolsep`, probably in combination with a reduced font size might help. Reducing the width of colmn headers or introducing linebreaks there can also help. There is unfortunately no single solution that suits all purposes. For more idesas, see also: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144)

Comment: @leandriis thanks a lot, very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}r}
    \hline 
    Description   & T & Source & Geography & Start & End & F \\ 
    \hline 

     \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Text}} \\ 

    Manchester United & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 10 &   \\
    Celtic            & 6 & 3 & 0 & 3 &  8 &   \\
    Benfica           & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  7 &   \\
    FC Copenhagen     & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &   \\

    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Text}} \\ 

    Manchester United & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 10 &   \\
    Celtic            & 6 & 3 & 0 & 3 &  8 &   \\
    Benfica           & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  7 &   \\
    FC Copenhagen     & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 &   \\

\end{tabular}
```